# Replace the "values" of the foreign key using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fetch

I've made a program that get the values of 2 tables.. I mean my program **just get the "id" of the tables (the foreign key) BUT IT DOES NOT SHOW THE VALUES that correspond to that id.**

My tables:

> "cursadas" includes:**(id, user_id[is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table "usuarios"], subject_id[is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table "materias"], grade, date)**
>
> "usuarios" includes:**(id,username,name,lastname,password,type,status,date)**
>
> "materias" includes:**(id, career_id, name, description, hours)**

Take a look at that, my program shows this table:

[image]

AND my goal is to show this table (the green one):

[image]

Dont know what to do, here is my code:

My view file ("home"):

```
    <html>

    <head>



    </head>

<body>

    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <h2 align="center">TABLE:Study</h2>

        <input id="busqueda_tabla" type="text">
            <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </thead>

<tbody>
    <?php

    if (count($records) > 0 && $records != false) {
        foreach($records as $record) {

            echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$record['id']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['user_id']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['subject_id']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['grade']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['date']."</td>
                      <td align='center'>

                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDIT</button></a> |

                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>DELETE</button></a>

                  </tr>";
        }

       }
    ?>

</tbody>

    </table>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller file ("Home")

```
    <?php

    class Home extends CI_Controller{

         public function __construct(){
             parent::__construct();

             $this->load->model("Crudmodel");

        }


 public function index(){

    # get all data in Study table
    $selectStudys = $this->Crudmodel->selectStudys();


    foreach ($selectStudys as $key => $study) 
    {
        # get UserNames
        $user = $this->Crudmodel->getName($study['user_id']);

        #get Subject Names
        $subject = $this->Crudmodel->getSubName($study['subject_id']);


        #append both NEW VALUES to same array

        if(!empty($user[0]['username'])){
        $data[$key]['user_id'] = $user[0]['username'];

        }else{
         $data[$key]['user_id'] = ''; // or anything as your else condition you can use as error handler 
        }
        if(!empty($subject[0]['name'])){
        $data[$key]['subject_id'] = $subject[0]['name'];

        }else{
           $data[$key]["subject_id"] = "";
          // or anything you can use as error handler
        }

    }


    $data['records'] = $selectStudys;
    $this->load->view('home', $data);

}

}
?>
```

My model file:

```
       <?php

    class Crudmodel extends CI_Model{

        public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();

         $this->load->database();

        }


function selectStudys()
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM cursadas");
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
       $result = $query->result_array();
     }else{
      $result = array();
    }
    return $result;
}

function getName($name)
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM usuarios WHERE id = $name ");
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
    $result = $query->result_array();
    }else{
    $result = "";
    }
          // or anything you can use as error handler
    return $result;
  }


function getSubName($subject)
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM materias WHERE id = $subject ");
  if($query->num_rows()>0){
     $result = $query->result_array();
  }else{
      $result = "";
          // or anything you can use as error handler
  }
      return $result;
}


 function CombineResults($subject, $name){
  // you can also use this
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT sub.name, user.username FROM materias sub, Users user WHERE sub.id=$subject AND user.id = $name");
   if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->result();
         }else{
           return array();
              // or anything you can use as error handler
        }
    }       
  }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wandering why you are using such a long script, you can simply do it using MySQL Join.

Here is the Query

```
SELECT a.id ID,b.username User, c.name, a.grade, a.date
FROM cursadas a 
JOIN usuarios b ON a.user_id=b.id 
JOIN materias c ON c.id=a.subject_id
```

Here is the link to SQLFIDDLE. [Click Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6ec05/3)

Model Code:

```
function your_function_name()
{
    $result = NULL;
    $query=$this->db->query('SELECT a.id ID,b.username User, c.name, a.grade, a.date FROM cursadas a JOIN usuarios b ON a.user_id=b.id JOIN materias c ON c.id=a.subject_id');
     if($query->num_rows()>0){
        $result = $query->result_array();
      }
    return $result;
}
```

Controller Code:

```
function your_controller_function()
{
  $this->load->model('your_model');
  $data['records'] = $this->your_model->your_function_name();
  $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

View Code:

```
<table>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>User</th><th>Subject</th><th>Grade</th><th>Date</th><th>Action</th></tr>
<?php
if($records)
{
  foreach($records as $rc)
  {
   <tr><td><?php echo $c->id;?></td>
   <td><?php echo $c->username;?></td>
   <td><?php echo $c->name;?></td>
   <td><?php echo $c->grade;?></td>
   <td><?php echo $c->date;?></td>
   <td><a href="#">Edit</a><a href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>
   }
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Mate, it seems to be right but in my code when i run it a message 404 page not found appeared :S

Comment: Take a look:
https://i.gyazo.com/f4521b6bea32f7d2f17289ee90c38ac9.png
https://i.gyazo.com/1edcc340b1dac4b493f2e783ba4f3bf4.png
https://i.gyazo.com/7cafbf1fcb865fa733a439fe007c0d21.png

Comment: I am sorry about that the query should be working fine without any modification.

Comment: Mate, it shows an error at line 25:
https://i.gyazo.com/bac61c0ef668ba111f7c95fe6e6079a1.png
https://i.gyazo.com/5b8ed92838362894eac053159aa45f9e.png

Comment: I updated the answer to fix the issue you are facing with the broken syntax on the foreach, its pending review though

Comment: Sorry Dear, due to time zone difference, I am unable to answer your comments. I have given a sample code, you have to use your own controller, model, and view as well as the methods in them. Generally, CodeIgniter returns 404 when it unable to locate any URL (path to your controller method). Some cases missing view file also return 404.